# MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT always contains null in Landscape mode

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

i am trying to open the camera and set a path to which the camera picture should be saved as shown in the following line:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(this.mFileImgPath))
```

the problem i have is, if i took the picture while the camera in the portrait mode then 'onActivityResult' will be called normally and when i check 'mFileImgPath' it wil be not null. But when i use the same code and take a picture
in the landscape mode, then 'onActivityResult' will be called but always 'mFileImgPath' is null.

to invstigate further, i used the debugger and 'mFileImgPath' is always null if i tried to take a picture in the Lanscape mode. pleae have a look at the screen shot of the debugger

please let me know why the 'mFileImgPath' is always null in landscape mode? and how to olve it

**code**

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        this.mFileImgPath = new File(App.instance.getOutDir() + "/" + new Date().getTime());
        Log.e(TAG, "mFileImgPath" + mFileImgPath);

        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(this.mFileImgPath));
```

**debugger**

[image]

as shown in the screen shot, the 'mFileImgPath' is null and when i click *steo over* the debugger skips the if-condition

Comment: `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT always contains null in Lanscape mode`. Wrong. Not true. Your String variable for your path is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known issue when working with inbuilt camera. In order to fix this you have to retain the uri via *onSaveInstanceState()* and *onRestoreInstanceState()*.

- Before your declare the *`startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)`* , declare *intent.putExtra(..)* so:

  ```
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
  startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
  ```
- Now put these 2 methods in your activity

  ```
        /* Storing the file url as it'll be null after returning from camera app */
   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
   }

   @Override
       protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)         {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
  }
  ```
- Do not try to access *`Intent`* in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` , the parameter `data` is most likely going to be null.

Comment: thanks you..but you said "Do not try to access Intent in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) , the parameter data is most likely going to be null." ..why it will be null??

Comment: When you launch camera it actually restart your activity thus causing your uri to be null.

Comment: ok fine..what if did not use "onRestoreInstanceState"..and just saved my current state in "onSaveInstanceState" and then get the save instances from the bundle in onCreate??

Comment: As far as I know putParcelable will save your uri in external storage mechanism, I've never accessed the saved path in onCreate, but via onRestoreInstanceState, you can try it to find out. I'm quite sure it will work though.

Comment: actually i am trying to send File through the bundle..and i used "putParcealable" as you suggested but then Android studio suggest casting the File object to Parcealable and at run time i receive the following:  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

Your activity can be killed when the camera app is up. Activities not on fore ground can at any time be killed by Android.

You should @overide onSaveInstanceState and save the value of the path variable there. Then retrieve the value in onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: Did you google for those functions? You would have found many examples.